# How is it possible that loop-recur throws a StackOverflowError?

Tags: clojure, tail-recursion

I´ve been trying to implement a tail-recursive version of chainl1, but even with the loop-recur it throws a StackOverflowError. How is that possible and what can i do to change that?

```
(defn atest [state]
  (when-not (and (= "" state) (not (= (first state) \a))) 
      (list (first state) (. state (substring 1)))))
(defn op [state]
  (when-not (and (= "" state) (not (= (first state) \a)))
    (list #(list :| %1 %2) (. state (substring 1)))))
(defn chainl1-helper [x p op]
  (fn [state]
    (loop [x x
           state state]
      (if-let [xs (op state)]
        (when-let [xs2 (p (second xs))]
          (recur ((first xs) x (first xs2)) (second xs2)))
        (list x state)))))

(defn chainl1 [p op]
  (fn [state]
    (when-let [[v s] (p state)]
      ((chainl1-helper v p op) s))))
(def test-parse (chainl1 atest op))
(defn stress-test [n] (test-parse (apply str (take n (interleave (repeat "a") (repeat "+"))))))
(stress-test 99999)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

its printing the final result that blows the stack
so it's the REPL not your code.

replace the last line with

```
(count (stress-test 99999))
```

and it finishes

the stack trace has this pattern repeating many times:

```
 13:    core_print.clj:58 clojure.core/print-sequential
 14:    core_print.clj:140 clojure.core/fn
 15:      MultiFn.java:167 clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke
```

EDIT: LDomagala pointed out *print-level* as a safety against this sort of crash

```
user>  (set! *print-level* 20)
20
user> (stress-test 9999)
((:f (:f (:f (:f (:f (:f (:f (:f (:f (:f (:f (:f (:f (:f (:f (:f (:f (:f (:f # \a) \a) \a) \a) \a) \a) \a) \a) \a) \a) \a) \a) \a) \a) \a) \a) \a) \a) \a) "")
user>
```

Comment: i´ve been told that you can also use (set! *print-level* 20) so only part of the result gets printed and the stack doesn't get blown.